# Código Jquery não chama Metodo no controler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Não estou sabendo como usar um método `jQuery`. Quero obter uma lista de países. Segue o código pra ajudar em saber onde estou errando.

```js
  < script type = "text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#btnPais').click(function(e) {
          $('#btnPais').hide();
          $('#mensagem').html('<span class="mensagem">Aguarde, carregando ..</span>');

          $.getJSON('/Usuario/ObterPaises', function(dados) {
            if (dados.length > 0) {
              var option = '<option value="">Escolha um Pais </option>';
              $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
                option += '<option value="' + obj.PaisId + '">' + obj.Nome + "- " + obj.Sigla + '</option>';
              })
              $('#mensagem').html('<span class="mensagem">Total de paises encontrados.: ' + dados.length + '</span>');
              $('#cmbPais').html(option);
            } else {
              $('#mensagem').html('<span class="mensagem">Não foi encontrado nenhum país</span>');
            }
          })
        })
        //<!-- Resetar Selects -->

      function Reset() {
        $('#cmbPais').empty().append('<option>Carregar Países</option>>');
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="pais">
  <label>Selecione o País:</label>
  <select id="cmbPais">
    <option>Carregar Paises</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="carregar pais" id="btnPais" class="bottom" />
</div>
```

e no meu Controller tenho :

```
 [HttpGet]
 public JsonResult ObterPaises()
{
   Comandos cm = new Comandos();
   string sql = "Select Nome FROM TPais";
   List<Pais> pais = new List<Pais>();

   var dr = cm.SelectReader(sql, CommandType.Text);
   while (dr.Read())
   {
      pais.Add(new Pais
      {
          PaisId = (int)dr[0],
          Nome = dr[1].ToString(),
          Sigla = dr[2].ToString()
      });
    }
    return Json(pais, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Segundo o que pesquisei, usando este código, era pra me retornar a lista certa, porem, nem entra no método **ObterPaises** do controller.

Aberto a sugestões que possam me levar ao entendimento de como fazer.

Comment: `$each` = [**`$.each`**](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: Fiz a correção, agora entra no controller. porem não devolve nenhum dado para View

Comment: É porque em momento algum você insere o conteúdo da variável `option` no select. Só está concatenando as `<option>` nela. :)

Comment: Resolvido, suas dicar foram fundamentais. Obrigado !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opção 1: Mudar o retorno do controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult ObterPaises()
{
   Comandos cm = new Comandos();
   string sql = "Select id, nome, sigla FROM TPais";

   var dr = cm.SelectReader(sql, CommandType.Text);
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   while (dr.Read())
   {
      sb.AppendFormat("<option value={0}>{1} - {2}", dr[0], dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString())
    }
    return Json(sb.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

E na view:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnPais').click(function(e) {
      $('#btnPais').hide();
      $('#mensagem').html('<span class="mensagem">Aguarde, carregando ..</span>');

      $.getJSON('/Usuario/ObterPaises', function(dados) {
        if (dados.length > 0) {
          $('#cmbPais').html("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>"); //opcional
          $('#cmbPais').append(dados);
          $('#mensagem').html('<span class="mensagem">Total de paises encontrados.: ' + dados.length + '</span>');
          $('#cmbPais').html(option);
        } else {
          $('#mensagem').html('<span class="mensagem">Não foi encontrado nenhum país</span>');
        }
      })
    })

});
```

Opção 2: Alterar o método atual para que olhe para a sua variável de retorno do get:

```
$.getJSON('/Usuario/ObterPaises', function(dados) {
        if (dados.length > 0) {
          var option = '<option value="">Escolha um Pais </option>';
          $.each(dados.pais, function(i, obj) { //Mudança aqui <<
            option += '<option value="' + obj.PaisId + '">' + obj.Nome + "- " + obj.Sigla + '</option>';
          })
          $('#mensagem').html('<span class="mensagem">Total de paises encontrados.: ' + dados.length + '</span>');
          $('#cmbPais').html(option);
        } else {
          $('#mensagem').html('<span class="mensagem">Não foi encontrado nenhum país</span>');
        }
})
```

Comment: Marlon, no controller

      while (dr.Read())
      {
        sb.AppendFormat("<option value={0}>{1} - {2}", dr[0],    dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString())
       }

**Me retorna o erro: "O índice estava fora dos limites da matriz."**

Comment: Renan, basta colocar para selectar o que você quer na query: `Select Id, Nome, Sigla FROM TPais`